# When to repair Bhakti

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I am on my first play-through, in Oerba, I have all the parts to repair Bhakti but am unsure if I should repair him now or wait, as I am pretty sure I havn't held every item/weapon in game. Should/can I wait? Or will he give me titles twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you come back to Bhakti later, he will reward you new titles and trophies if you've fulfilled the requirements for them since the last time you visited him. So, there's no reason not to repair him the first chance you get.